# Is $e^{\pm 2\pi i/3}=1$ in the splitting field of $x^3-t\in \mathbb{F}_3(t)[x]$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, splitting-field

Let $F=\mathbb{F}_3(t)$, where $t$ is a variable.

Then if $a$ is a root of $x^3-t\in F[x]$ in its splitting field we have
$$
x^3-t=(x-a)^3=(x-\omega a)^3.
$$
where $\omega$ is an abstract 3rd root of unity.

> Q: Does this mean that $\omega=1$ in the splitting field of $x^3-t$?

Comment: How do you define $e^{2\pi i/3}$?

Comment: There is no such thing as $e^{2\pi i/3}$ in any field of characteristic $3$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Cox uses the roots of unity in arbitrary field $F$ on page 86. Can you see the edited question, is it ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The splitting field of $x^3-t$ is $\Bbb F_3(a)$. This is a normal
but inseparable extension of $\Bbb F_3(t)$ with degree $3$.

In every field of characteristic $3$, there is only one cube root of unity, $1$ itself.

Comment: I thought this too, but there were doubts. Both answers are correct, but I accept this one because it was earlier. Please can you see this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461515/alternative-proof-of-proposition-5-2-1-from-book-galois-theory-by-d-cox ?

Answer (score 2):

In any field of characteristic $p>0$, the only $p$th root of unity is $1$.  Indeed, if $\omega$ is a $p$th root of unity, then $\omega^p-1=0$.  But $\omega^p-1=(\omega-1)^p$, so $\omega-1=0$.